# private named parameter in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Dart. Let's say I have a `final List <Character> _characterList;` which should be private. But how do I use `CharacterList ({Key key, this._characterList}): super (key: key);` if the named parameter cannot start with _?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The name of the *parameter* is independent of the name of the *member*.  Constructors offer the `this.name` syntactic sugar for convenience if the names happen to be the same, but you don't have to use that.  You could give the parameter its own name and explicitly initialize the member variable separately:

```dart
CharacterList({Key? key, required List<Character> characterList})
  : _characterList = characterList,
    super(key: key);

final List<Character> _characterList;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is Dart [limitation](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/3642#issuecomment-453929607)

```
Named optional parameters can't start with an underscore
```

You can use a constructor with optional positional parameter instead

```
CharacterList (Key key, [this._characterList]): super (key: key)
```